# Pass a file as a command line argument with temporarily altered text

Tags: sed, command-line

Here's the scenario:

- A command-line command requires an input file as an argument
- The input file I want to use has text in it that I want the command to ignore
- I cannot create a temporary file with the bad text removed

I tried using `sed`, using a regex to find the bad text, and replace it with nothing. The output of `sed` could be saved into a temporary file, and that file passed to the command as the input file argument, however like I said, I cannot create a temporary file. Is there a) a way to directly pipe the output of `sed` as the input file argument, or b) a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 1):

This is `bash`-specific *"process substitution"*:

```
command <(sed 's/bad//g' somefile)
```

Your program, `command` in this instance, will see a filename like `/dev/fd63` as its parameter.

Comment: The OP did say he can't create a temp file... idk why or what exactly he means by that of course so this may be OK.

Comment: @EdMorton I don’t know either:-) Maybe `bash` can create temporary files and filehandles even if OP can’t.

Answer (score 1):

With no temp file created:

```
sed 's/bad//g' file | command
```

or if a "file" name is absolutely necessary as an argument to your command:

```
sed 's/bad//g' file | command -
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5

$ sed 's/3//g' file | awk '{print FILENAME, $0}'
- 1
- 2
-
- 4
- 5
```

If that's not what you want (e.g. if you need to parse the input file multiple times within your command) then edit your question to clarify your requirements and include concise, testable sample input and expected output.